# How to redirect only homepage /index.php to / and not apply for orther page in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a home page: homepage/index.php and admin page: homepage/admin/index.php. And I want to redirect only homepage from .index.php to non .index.php. I am tried with code:

It's redirect all to root domain.com. How can apply for homepage only? Thanks

This is for new Linux server, running MySQL 5, PHP 5, Nginx and Apache 2.

```
      rewrite ^(.*/)index\.(php?)$ $1 permanent;
    }
```

I want to redirect only homepage.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/index\.(php?)$ / permanent;`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your option but failed. I try the orther way:

```
rewrite ^/index\.php?$ scheme://$host/ redirect;
```